# How can I generate a unique array by combining two same array values?

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose, I have an array

```
$array1 = array(10, 20);
```

and another array of same values as above

```
$array2 = array(10, 20);
```

I want to combine these two arrays and generate an array with unique key and value pair. I want `$array3` output to be like this:

```
$array3 = array(10 => 20, 20 => 10)
```

I tried shuffling the second array (`$array2`), sometimes it gives me the same values as first one(`$array1`). And my `$array3` output is:

```
$array3 = array(10 => 10, 20 => 20)
```

Comment: Why `10 => 20, 20 => 10`?

Comment: will there always be only two pairs of key and value?

Comment: @nbin No. Values can be upto 3 or 4 for an array. But two array values are always same. I want to generate an array with unique pair of keys and values. No key and value should be the same.

Comment: @Wahyu Kristianto I'm working on a custom application in which a users' file needs to be exchanged with some other user.

Answer (score 1):

```
array_combine($array1, array_reverse($array2));
```

That will achieve the `$array3` that you specified in the example you provided, but in general will not work unless `$array1` and `$array2` have the same number of values.

I'm a little confused about what you really need. Can you provide another example with more keys / values?

Comment: I have two arrays of same values.

$array1 = array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
$array2 = array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);

Two arrays will always have same number of values. I want a new array, which new array key and value should not be the same.

Comment: Your algorithm is good. However it fails at
$array1 = array(10, 20, 30);
$array2 = array(10, 20, 30);

Comment: then pair of keys and values doesnt matter as long as they are not same. yah?

Comment: then above answer does your job.

Comment: http://ideone.com/9SHyqN - It does not fail for the example you gave in your comments. Can you provide any more explanation on how it fails?